# Mkdocstrings error "No module named" when using monorepo plugin

Tags: python, mkdocs-material, mkdocstrings

I am using the **monorepo plugin** to create nested documentations of my repo packages. I have a lot of packages, but the basic structure of the repo is:

```
root
|- mkdocs.yml
|- docs
|- components
  |- packages
    |- package1
      |- mkdocs.yml
      |- docs
         |- api.md
      |- folder_with_py_files
        |- file.py
```

All is working fine with **monorepo plugin**, but when I try to build the documentation without having installed the packages, is not finding them, and I'm even using the `path:[]` at both levels inside all the `mkdocs.yml`, the package and the root ones.

Inside the .md file, I'm calling the module using:

```
::: folder_with_py_files.file
```

But the error persists that is not importing the module correctly, and thus is failing when trying to build the root documentation:

```
ERROR   -  mkdocstrings: Importing 'folder_with_py_files.file' failed, possible causes are:
- an exception happened while importing
- an element in the path does not exist
...
ERROR   -  Error reading page 'package1/api.md':
ERROR   -  Could not collect 'folder_with_py_files.file'

Aborted with a BuildError!
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you specified `path`, that's a typo: it should be `paths` (plural).

```yaml
plugins:
- mkdocstrings:
    handlers:
      python:
        paths:
        - components/packages/package1
        - components/packages/package2
```

See https://mkdocstrings.github.io/python/usage/#finding-modules.